# How do I Render the Market Cap automatically to the page which is a result of stock price * shares outstanding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was doing a 45 day coding with ReactJS challenge am on day 2 and I have encountered a slight issue ,
I was wondering how I could render the Marketcap without the need to click submit button onto to the page and also the form space

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

class App extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state= {
                StockName:"",
                StockPrice:"",
                Volume:"",
                MarketCap:""

        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.Calculate=this.Calculate.bind(this)

    }
    handleChange(event){
        const{name,value}=event.target
        this.setState({
            [name]:value
        })

    }

    Calculate(event){
        alert('$Market Cap is calculated')

    }

    render(){

        return(


            <main>
            <h1>Enter Company Details Below</h1>

            <form >
            <input 
            class="form-control form-control-lg"
            value= {this.state.StockName}  
            onChange ={this.handleChange}
            name ="StockName"
            placeholder="Stock" /><br />

            <input
            class="form-control form-control-sm" 
            value= {this.state.StockPrice} 
            onChange ={this.handleChange}
            name="StockPrice" 
            placeholder="$ Stock Price" /><br />
           <input
           class="form-control form-control-sm"     
            value= {this.state.Volume} 
            onChange ={this.handleChange}
            name="Volume" 
            placeholder="Shares Outstanding" />
            <br />

           <input
           class="form-control form-control-sm"     
            value= {this.state.MarketCap} 
            onChange ={this.handleChange}
            name="MarketCap" 
            placeholder="$ Market Cap" />
            <br />
            <button onClick={this.Calculate}>Calculate</button>    

                </form>
                <br/>
                Company: <h1>{this.state.StockName}</h1>
                SharePrice: <p>${this.state.StockPrice}</p>
                Shares Outstanding : <p>{this.state.Volume}</p>
                Market Cap: <p>${this.state.MarketCap}</p>

                </main>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by rendering MarketCap, but if the point is to update it with every change you can trigger the calculate method from the change method. Example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/345yr934x5